# Match urls mysql

Tags: php, sql, mysql

```
$value = 'http://www.mydomain.com/this-is-page-one'
```

I have a field in my mysql table called "urls" which stores different urls inside, like:

```
http://www.bdsada.com/dsadsfsaf
http://www.comddsad.com/dsadacsdfs
```

and so on

I want to best match my value with on of the urls. - do an sql query
Maybe the number of repeatting letters.

Please give an actual example.... pleaseee

Comment: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/string-comparison-functions.html#operator_like

Comment: When you say "best match", do you mean to match like *www.bdsada.com* with an input of *bdsad*, or do you mean best match based on Levenshtein distance? Can you give an example of input vs. expected output?

Comment: Based on Levenshtein distance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure exactly what you mean by the 'best match'.  Say that you are storing the urls in the database as listed above (http://www.website.com/extension).  Also, that the input may or may not include the 'http://', 'www.', or any additional GET variables in the URL.  Before you submit the string for the database query, I would do the following:

To strip the 'http://' or 'https://' from the url.

```
$valueStrip = explode("//",$value);
$value = $valueStrip[1];
```

To strip out any get variables

```
$valueStrip = explode("?",$value);
$value = $valueStrip[0];
```

Also, make sure you clean it for any SQL injection attack, this should work

```
$value = mysql_real_escape_string($value);
```

Let assume that 'url' is the name of the table and 'domainName' is the column name for the actual domain name.  So, your query could look like this

```
$query = mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query("SELECT url FROM domainName WHERE url LIKE '%$value%'"));
```

I should note that I haven't tested the code and it could be made more efficient.